# Ax=b Clustering

Tags: linear-algebra, sparse-matrices

I came across a very common multi-modal robustness problem.

I have a simple linear equation set $Ax=b$ that I need to solve.
Obviously, SVD can be used for a least-squares solution for $x$.

However, the rows of $A_{N \times M}$ and $b$ come from $k$ different sources ($k \ll N$), so that there is not just one $x$ which is the solution but $k$ true $x$s.
In fact, if I could cluster/segment my data sources for each source separately the solution would be much more precise with a separate $x$ for each such cluster.

Is there a robust algorithm (reasonably fast would be nice too) for solving for such multiple $x$ and $k$? Maybe from the low-rank/sparse matrix decomposition literature? I am not familiar with the exact terms to search for.

What if $k$ is known?
What if $k$ is not known?

Any reference would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "so that there is not just one x which is the solution but k true xs" - I think here is a mistake . A system of linear equations can have 0, 1 or an infinity of solutions . The problem seems superficially like ICA ( independent component analysis ) .

Comment: Basically, these are really $k$ different linear equation sets, but I don't know how many and the rows are mixed. I am asking about how to unmix them and solve for the $k$ $x$s.

Comment: If you have multiple independent signal sources and what you observe is a linear combination ( with unknown ) coefficients , you can use independent component analysis . You can take a look here for example  http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes11.pdf  , maybe this will help clarify the objective .

Comment: Each of my "observations" (rows of $A$ and $b$) come only from one of $k$ sources. So the coefficients would be all $0$s except one which is $1$ (at an unknown position). Hence the sparsity context. Is ICA still the right solution? How do I formulate this?

Comment: I guess a toy example will be very useful .